# How to automatically adjust the size of a QTableView

Tags: linux, qt, qt-creator, qtableview

I've got a table view inside the main window of a Qt application.

[image]

How can I get the table view widget automatically resize after resizing the main window? I need all borders of the table view to retain their distance to the borders of the main window (or to the borders of nearest widget, like the "Fetch Data" button). I have created this widget through the Qt Designer IDE. Is there any property I should set via the properties panel on the right side of Qt Creator to achieve my purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You need a layout manager. The distances can then be set by the left,right,top,bottom margins.

Comment: Not too much more to say. When you are in the designer, there are four buttons in the top row: Lay Out vertically, Lay Out horizontally, Lay out in a Form, Lay Out in a Grid. Select the root widget of your design and click on one of those buttons. Which one depends on your design requirements. Most likely you need the vertical layout. But it is a bit of trial and error to really get the layout you like until you get more experienced how to use the designer.

Comment: Btw... sorry. I know my answer is a bit 'terse'. But it is really hard to walk you through a graphical design process here. You might want to look for some youtube tutorials on the designer, e.g.http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LYF0spYkXUs or http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9E2KOphwZMg

Comment: Thank you very much. Let me see if I can find my way through it.